# Finding filters that are used by the Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action-filter

I am working on a controller action that needs to check which actions require the user to log in, which is controlled by a `before_filter`, so I need to check what filters are being used by a given controller. Is there an array or a property where the filters are being stored that can be access by my program?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to get access to filters:

```
SomeController.send(:_process_action_callbacks)
```

BUT! I do not recommend you to use it. It's storming into ActiveSupport guts. Developers did not counted on that anybody will use these private methods. If I were you I would change the architecture to do not depend on these tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found what I was looking for: [`filter_chain`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a1eb4e11c2cccb91483fa15f1a1a0b2ae518d2cf/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb#L573)